# How to structure my sharepoint 2007 xslt to sum

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm having a little trouble with some syntax for my xslt statement on a custom sharepoint page, any help would be much appricated.

I've summed a column from a list and it displays correctly (code below):

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Capex), '$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00')" />
```

However what won't work is when I try to apply a condition to the summed column.  For example I am trying to Sum only where projects are still active.  I have the code below, and would appricate any thoughts to get it working.

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[(@Capex) and (@ProjectStatus)='Active'])" />
```

The result of the above is NaN, so assume I need to do some formatting of the non-numeric section, I just haven't been able to get that working. Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the filter after the sum element.  Something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@Capex[@ProjectStatus='Active'])" />
```

There are some more examples here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846850/sum-contents-of-column-based-on-a-variable-with-xpath - which may help you to refine the formula.